# Factsheets from R - cat(), flexdashboard() or Markdown?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, reproducible-research, flexdashboard

I am looking to create Factsheets to demonstrate standardized information for about 20 projects. I want this information to be updated weekly (to observe progress) and be an HTML file. I was thinking of creating something like this: http://htaindex.cnt.org/fact-sheets/?focus=cbsa&gid=741

I have three options I could use:

- **The frenkenstein approach**: I could write all the html for a dummy factsheet, then mush my data into it in R and output the file with `cat()`. If I really wanted to be fancy I could even define custom functions that would elegantly mush the data together with html so that the implementers wouldn't have a heart attack at the wall of html and css.
- **The limited approach**: I could use flexdashboards which allows for assets to be placed in row or column orientation but not really a combination. This would limit my creative options, but is much faster and more reproducible, debuggable, etc
- **The correct approach**: I guess people will say that I should build a markdown template as documented [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_custom_formats.html), but that seems incredibly time-intensive and it looks as though I would have to get very familiar with pandoc, which I'm not looking forward to.

My question (hopefully not too wide) then is: Why shouldn't I just use the Frankenstein approach?

Comment: Another “correct” approach would be to use the ‹brew› package rather than — or in conjunction with — Rmarkdown. That’s what I’d recommend. This is definitely *less* time-intensive than the Frankenstein approach, and you don’t need any familiarity with pandoc.

Comment: If you want html, you might want to use shiny instead?

Comment: shiny won't work... I have to embed into a SharePoint site... so everything has to be static.